# Opentherm protocol - pcb design question

Tags: pcb-design, analog

I'm challenging creation of PCB that would allow me to talk to my boiler using specifics of so called OpenTherm protocol.

Till now I have learned the following:

> - Polarity is interchangeable on 2 wires
> - Data is signalled in changes in voltage and current
> - Boiler sends data as change in current where '1' is 17..23mA and '0' is 5..9ma
> - Room unit (which I want to make here ) is sending data as changes in voltage where '1' is 15..18 V and '0' is max 7V

My problem here is that I would like to understand ( hence asking for explanation ) about PCB design that I have found and would like to use here

[image]

Q1 : Could someone verify if this design would work as expected to properly communicate with my room unit ?

Q2 : Any explanation for someone stepping into world of analog components would be appreciated.

Thanks
Raf

Comment: > *Data is signalled in changes in voltage and current*
Either, not both. No supply in this world can control both current and voltage.

Comment: Where did you find this? It's generally a good idea to cite your sources, if for respect and copyright reasons alone.

Comment: And also, without you telling us what VCC is, we can't answer Q1. Also, why should we verify *someone else's* circuit? If it was *your* circuit, yeah, well, we can discuss that, because there's something to discuss – you'd know why you'd design your circuit that way. The way you ask this is more of a usage then a electronic design question. Maybe you could explain what you've understood and what you didn't, so that answers could be more compact? That would be better, I think :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller. So to say I have found an image of circuit when browsing the internet. So I cannot provide exactly who the author would be. 
I have added to circuit the bridge rectifier ( as on image I have found it was just using 4 diodes ).
The VCC is 5V.
To answer what I understood : When I'm sending data ( so using optocoupler OK1A ) this is supposed to change the voltage on the line from idle state of 7V to those 15 and here is where I dont quite get the PNP there. For sending data I'm believe use of voltage divider and drop to 5V is used from what I can read.